trying to get form post to show in curl
please help. I have a form that posts a SIM ID to this page to get the SIM's status.
But I need the $sim to show in the curl $sim
<?php
$sim = $_POST['sim'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://.../thing/$sim/state/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ...,
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

print "Status of Sim?: " . $response;

curl_close($ch);

?>

Thanks for the help

Single quotes means string literal, so that means it literally contains the text /$sim/. You can either change them to double quotes, or properly concatenate the value e.g /' . $sim . '/

this worked perfect :)
